# window resize not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a number of javascript functions. In order to stop the resize event firing twice, I implemented a fix, which has been working perfectly to date.

```
function tabsResize() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        tabsUpdate();
    }, 200);
}

$(window).on("resize", tabsResize);
```

However, I've just created another function, which sits slighly lower in the food chain but does exactly the same thing.

```
var form = function () {
    var pub = {}, timeout;

function textareaAutoGrow() {
    var pad = $(this).outerHeight(false) - $(this).innerHeight();

    this.style.height = "auto";
    this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight + pad) + "px";
}

function textareaResize() {
    alert("resize");
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        textareaAutoGrow();
    }, 200);
}

function setupBindings() {
    $("body").on("input", "textarea", textareaAutoGrow);
    $(window).on("resize", textareaResize);
}

// PUBLIC FUNCTIONS

pub.init = function () {
    setupBindings();
}

return pub;
} ();
```

The problem is that it is not triggering - the autogrow function works and there are no javascript errors I can see - it's just the resize function.

In order to check whether it was in fact firing, I added the alert. Still no joy.

However, when I also added a second alert to the tabs resize function both alerts fired. I'm guessing this is some kind of timing issue, but I just don't know how to fix it.

Anyone advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[first code demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jy7yfwov/)

```js
var _timeOut = null;

function tabsResize() {
    if(typeof(_timeOut))
        clearTimeout(_timeOut);
    _timeOut = setTimeout(function () {
        alert('=)');
    }, 200);
}

$(window).on("resize", tabsResize);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**[Second code Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jkn6o7b8/)**

```js
var _timeOut = null;

var form = function () {
    var pub = {}, timeout;

function textareaAutoGrow() {
    alert('=)');
    var pad = $(this).outerHeight(false) - $(this).innerHeight();

    this.style.height = "auto";
    this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight + pad) + "px";
}

function textareaResize() {
    alert("resize");
    
    if(typeof(_timeOut))
       clearTimeout(_timeOut);
    _timeOut = setTimeout(function () {
        textareaAutoGrow();
    }, 300);
}

    $("body").on("input", "textarea", textareaAutoGrow);
    $(window).on("resize", textareaResize);

return pub;
} ();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've not gone quiet - just testing.

Comment: Seems to be working consistently with revised code from demo1 - marked as answer.